# Upgrading Typescript from 4.4.4 to 4.5.5 for express app: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, typescript

App was building fine running `npm run build` from `"typescript": "^4.4.4"`

but after updating to `"typescript": "^4.5.5"` the build fails with this message, it doesn't point to where or how to debug the issue and the code base is of decent size, my best guess according to the changes in the change log would be the [tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) how can i track what is causing this error for me?

> npm run build

```sh
    > app@1.0.0 build
    > tsc
    
    C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:94453
    throw e;
    ^
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at recursiveTypeRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:52989:44)
    at isRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:52657:34)
    at isPropertySymbolTypeRelated (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:53650:24)
    at propertyRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:53682:31)
    at propertiesRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:53870:43)
    at structuredTypeRelatedToWorker (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:53099:28)
    at structuredTypeRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:53093:30)
    at recursiveTypeRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:53064:53)
    at isRelatedTo (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:52674:31)
    at typeRelatedToSomeType (C:\project_path\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:52878:35)
```

package.json script

```
"build": "tsc",
```

tsconfig.json

```json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "typeRoots": [
           "./src/Types"
         ], 
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "Database/**/*"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: To me this sounds like a circular or malformed export. Check your code for something like `export * from './'` or circular imports

Comment: could this be an issue in one of the node modules? i reverted my updates and updated only typescript with the same result. something changed with typescript compilation, but i'll check my imports and exports